# Getting array out of ArrayOutOfBound exception. I was writing code to get first letters of all words in a string

Tags: java, arrays, string

//.  I was writing code to get first letters of all words in a string.
public class Firstword {

```
static void func(String str)
{
    String k ="";
   String str1=" "+str;
    char[] ch= str1.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length-2;i++)
        {
            if(i != ch.length-1)
            while(i<ch.length && ch[i]!=' ')
                i++;

            k=k+ch[i+1];
        }
    System.out.print(k);
    System.out.print(ch.length);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "Hello Banner jee";

    func(str);
}
```

}

Comment: Better approach would be to split the input on space. Then you have list on words and just take the 1st char from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
  k=k+ch[i+1];
```

You are getting out of bounds.

Because of this:

```
  while(i<ch.length && ch[i]!=' ')
            i++;
```

Something like this will work -

```
static void func(String str)
{
String [] words = str.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < words.length ;i++){
    System.out.println(words[i].charAt(0));
}
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
String str = "Hello Banner jee";
func(str);
}
```

Output -

```
H
B
j
```

Comment: Thnx a lot sir, but can u pls explain,the value of a[i+1] are a[1],a[7] and a[14] and array is of 17 characters then are we going out of bound ?